# Cannot find symbol (Constructor)

Tags: java, constructor

Code wont create an object using the my constructor:

```
public class IsEscapeDownChecker extends Thread {
ServerSocket socket;

public IsEscapeDownChecker(ServerSocket serversocket) {
    socket = serversocket;
}
```

Here is where i call it up in my main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1111);
    IsEscapeDownChecker isEscapeDown = new IsEscapeDownChecker(server);
```

But i get the error:

```
  C:\Users\B4\Documents\Java\TEstBlue\BluetoothRCServer.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        IsEscapeDownChecker isEscapeDown = new IsEscapeDownChecker(server);
        ^
  symbol:   class IsEscapeDownChecker
  location: class BluetoothRCServer
C:\Users\B4\Documents\Java\TEstBlue\BluetoothRCServer.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        IsEscapeDownChecker isEscapeDown = new IsEscapeDownChecker(server);
                                               ^
  symbol:   class IsEscapeDownChecker
  location: class BluetoothRCServer
2 errors
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? The first file with the constructor compiles as normal, and both files are in the same folder ect. The main metod just wont recognise the constructor.

*Edit:

Here are my imports:

```
package com.AJD1.bluetoothrc;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
```

Here is are pastebins of codes:

[Main](https://pastebin.com/Y8xscyuZ)

[Constructor](https://pastebin.com/RpYRYZT6)

Comment: what is the constructor of `ServerSocket `?

Comment: are those files in the same package? You seem to be missing `import`s.

Comment: I am importing the needed imports, added what i'm importing.

Comment: well, you are not importing `IsEscapeDownChecker`.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that the error message says the *class* cannot be found, rather than the constructor. You need to either put `BluetoothRCServer` and `IsEscapeDownChecker` in the same package, or add an import for `IsEscapeDownChecker`.